# Storage displayed discrepancy from actual hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, php, hard-drive, apache-2.4

In our Ubuntu 14.04 server we have a 1TB Hard drive. The hard drive is displays as 998GB with 1% usage, however, with PHP software such as owncloud, it is only displaying 19GB of storage available. Is there anything I can do to let PHP utilize the whole hard drive rather than what could be a partition?

Here's the `df -h` output:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you put `/var/www` (or whatever directory you use for your web root) on a separate, smaller partition. While some people say there are advantages to this, I personally would just repartition everything to a single partition per drive. (downvoted because of lack of info, no lsblk nor df -h output)

Comment: added the df -h output

Comment: André, I must thank you, you've solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if there is any quota set in owncloud config. If there isn't, check how your disk is partitioned. Is the whole 1TB under `/` filesystem, or is it divided into smaller `/`, `/home`, `/boot` and so on. `df -h` shows this clearly.